# Run HTML5/CSS3 in UIWebView

Tags: ipad, html, css, uiwebview, ios-simulator

I've a problem that i couldn't solve, i wanna run the [Apple - HTML5 Showcase - Gallary](http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/gallery/)

in `UIWebView` inside my ipad app.

I've tried a local html file:

```
NSString *strr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo-gallery" ofType:@"html"];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:strr encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
[webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
```

and also a server html file, but it didn't work, can anyone help me, i wanna show an html5/css3 in `UIWebView`.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi this is what you can do

```
           UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
           //getthe path of the local html file
           NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileNamePath];

           NSURLRequest *aRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];
           //load the html file into the web view.
           [aWebView loadRequest:aRequest];

           //add the web view to the content view
           [view addSubview:aWebView];
```

For server html you simply skip the second line, and put the address.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at phonegap. Its a complete framework for building html5 apps inside a UIWebview with native capabilities.

See: http://www.phonegap.com

Comment: I've another requirement in my app, so i can't build it in phonegap, is there another way ?

Comment: sure there are other ways, but you can do anything in phonegap that you can in a normal objective-c app

Comment: I've to show a 3d models with integration a CRM system, it's a huge app, and i didn't try phonegap before, i did some project using it, but i'm not familier with phonegap, i just wanna display a 360 panorama image, i've tried panoramagl but it didn't work, alway give an error, can you put me in the correct line ?!